# How to add font awesome to select option in mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-awesome

I want to add symbols to my selected list. I put the text in the header. When I tried to use the icon in the selected menu, it did not work on mobile. But it works perfectly outside the selection menu. Is it possible to place the icon in the menu select option or is it simply impossible to do? How can I do this?

In Computer

[image: star]

In mobile

[image: mobile]

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">

<select class="form-control" id="reading_skill" name="reading_skill[]">
    <option value="1">&#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="2">&#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="3">&#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="4">&#xf006; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="5">&#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
</select>
```

css

```
select#listening_skill, select#writing_skill, select#reading_skill, select#level {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    /*content: '&#xf006;';*/
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Try using the CDN.

Comment: Please, give address?

Comment: Visit https://fontawesome.com/start and there you will get the link.

Comment: Did you mean that? <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

Comment: I changed this `<script src="kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>`. But my problem did not solve yet in mobile.

Comment: No, not that. After you create a kit, there will be a `<link>` snippet. You would need to copy that code.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on IOS 14 (iPad) - linking from the cloudflare CDN.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
select#listening_skill, select#writing_skill, select#reading_skill, select#level {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    /*content: '&#xf006;';*/
    font-weight: 900;
}
</style>
</head>
<select class="form-control" id="reading_skill" name="reading_skill[]">
    <option value="1">&#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="2">&#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="3">&#xf006; &#xf006; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="4">&#xf006; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
    <option value="5">&#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005; &#xf005;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I changed this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`. But my problem did not solve yet in mobile.

Comment: Does my snippet work on mobile - and what mobile device are you using. I tested on IOS14 and it was OK.

Comment: I use in Android